# Unable to add to cart from new Arrivals and Best Sellers, Magento 1.9.3

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

Unable to add to cart from New Arrivals and Best Sellers from Home Page,

we did **not add any new modules or any customization** suddenly it is not working,

we are using **single page checkout**, it is **redirecting to "THE SHOPPING CART IS CURRENTLY EMPTY"**

from remaining all the places working fine.

Comment: i think its issue of formkey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the cache problem on New Block. On Cms you can add new block like this:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" _productsCount="8" cache_lifetime="1"}}
```

Or you can add to xml file. Add a cache block, in xml layout (cms.xml or page.xml) page where new product blongs.

```
<block type="catalog/product_new" name="newproducts" products_count="20" template="catalog/product/new.phtml">
```

`<action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>0</s></action>`  // add this line